# Final Cut Pro: Multi-Multiclips?

Tags: macos, final-cut-pro

I have several videos in the Browser that I can make a multiclip out of with no problems. Then I thought that it would be great to: Take a camera angle, shrink it, lay it on top of another one and use that SEQUENCE as an angle in a multiclip.

Final Cut Pro seems to not allow me to make multiclips from SEQUENCES. Is that right? **If so, are there any other options that do not require me to export the sequences first?**